# Calculating the map "induced" by the exterior product?

Tags: tensor-products

I have an exam coming up (for differential topology) and my professor said the exam would be mostly computation oriented (particular emphasis on $\mathbb{R}^3$). I have proven some results theoretically about tensors in Guillemen and Pollack and but am not really confident in computation. I believe he said we should be able to "compute" the map "induced" by the exterior product. To (hopefully) be more precise he had put on the board, given a matrix:

$$A : V \to V$$

compute the corresponding:

$$\wedge^kA : \wedge^k V \to \wedge^k V$$

This was my best guess at a direct computation, but I am unsure if I am doing it correctly:

For example, say we have the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

This is a map from $R^3 \to R^3$. Now I want to compute to compute:

$$\wedge^2 A : \wedge^2 R^3 \to \wedge^2R^3$$

I choose would then choose an ordered basis to be:

$$ \{ e^1\wedge e^2, e^1 \wedge e^3, e^2 \wedge e^3 \} $$

(I guess the order could change, but I assume this would be given in a question?)

I then apply $A^*$ to each of the basis to obtain a representation.

$$A^*e^1\wedge e^2$$
$$A^*e^1\wedge e^3$$
$$A^*e^2\wedge e^3$$

This becomes:

$$Ae^1\wedge Ae^2$$
$$Ae^1\wedge Ae^3$$
$$Ae^2\wedge Ae^3$$

This then implies:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} \wedge 
   \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} \wedge 
   \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \wedge 
   \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

In the case that the dimension is equal, I believe the wedge should be just the dot product, and that this reduces down to the numbers $5$, $6$, and $1$. Then this becomes:

$$\wedge^2 A = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 6 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Is this correct? Is this how you compute the "map induced" by the exterior product on a matrix? (Sorry if this has been answered, I have had trouble finding concrete computations of exterior algebras...)

Comment: "In the case that the dimension is equal, I believe the wedge should be just the dot product"...more like the cross product, especially in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: +1 This is a good, well-explained and well-motivated question, with an attempt by the author. However, I encourage you, at least if you have no success finding help on MSE, to just ask your lecturer and explain to him what you've explained to us. I'm sure he'll be willing (and obviously able) to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote by $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The space $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a three dimensional vector space and $\Lambda^2(A) \colon \Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \rightarrow \Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a linear map so it should be represented by a $3 \times 3$ matrix with respect to some choice of basis of $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Let us choose the basis $\mathcal{B} = (e_1 \wedge e_2, e_1 \wedge e_3, e_2 \wedge e_3)$. The order indeed matters and if would reorder our basis, we would get a different matrix (it would have the same columns, but in different order). To find $[\Lambda^2(A)]_{\mathcal{B}}$, we need to compute $\Lambda^2(A)(e_1 \wedge e_2), \Lambda^2(A)(e_1 \wedge e_3), \Lambda^2(A)(e_2 \wedge e_3)$ and express the result in terms of the basis $\mathcal{B}$.

For example,

\begin{align*}
\Lambda^2(A)(e_1 \wedge e_2) &= (Ae_1 \wedge Ae_2) = 
(3e_1 + e_2 + 2e_3) \wedge (e_1 + e_3) \\
&=  3 (e_1 \wedge e_1) + 3 (e_1 \wedge e_3) + e_2 \wedge e_1 + e_2 \wedge e_3 + 2(e_3 \wedge e_1) + 2(e_3 \wedge e_3) \\
&=3(e_1 \wedge e_3) + e_2 \wedge e_1 + e_2 \wedge e_3 + 2(e_3 \wedge e_1) \\&=
(-1)(e_1 \wedge e_2) + 3(e_1 \wedge e_3) - 2(e_1 \wedge e_3) + e_2 \wedge e_3 \\&= 
(-1) \cdot (e_1 \wedge e_2) + 1 \cdot (e_1 \wedge e_3) + 1 \cdot (e_2 \wedge e_3)
\end{align*}

Thus, the matrix $[\Lambda^2(A)]_{\mathcal{B}}$ will look like

$$ [\Lambda^2(A)]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & ? & ? \\ 1 & ? & ? \\
1 & ? & ? \end{pmatrix}. $$

The two other columns will be obtained by computing $\Lambda^2(A)(e_1 \wedge e_3)$ and $\Lambda^2(A)(e_2 \wedge e_3)$ similarly. Note that I have used the properties of the wedge product to cancel terms and reorder them (introducing a minus sign) in order to express $\Lambda^2(A)(e_1 \wedge e_2)$ in terms of the basis elements.

Comment: Ohhh! Thanks! (I believe there is a small computational error though: $e_1 \wedge e_1$ should be $e_2 \wedge e_1$?)

Comment: @Dair: Yep, thanks for catching that. I've corrected it.

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your long equation because it gave me a headache.  :-) Next time, `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`.

Comment: As for the math, I prefer the basis $e_2 \wedge e_3$, $e_3 \wedge e_1$, and $e_1\wedge e_2$.  These are the Hodge stars of $e_1$, $e_2$, and $e_3$ induced by the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Then you can see that $v\wedge w = \star(v \times w)$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: No problem, I didn't know that I could use align here. Regarding the choice of basis, I didn't want to introduce extra complication and structure so I chose the basis which one usually gives $\Lambda^k(V)$ (elements $e_I = e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_k}$ where $I$ is an increasing multi-index).

Comment: Fair enough.  It's just the $n=3$ case that makes it so tempting.