# Computation of the induced linear map by the exterior product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, maple, exterior-algebra

Given a matrix $$A:V\to V$$ and an integer $k$, is there a way of having the corresponding $$\wedge^k A: \wedge^k V \to \wedge^k V$$ computed by Maple? This question is linked with [Calculating the map "induced" by the exterior product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050136/calculating-the-map-induced-by-the-exterior-product) but my problem is that when the dimension of $V$ and $k$ are growing, it becomes rapidly unreasonable to do this computation by hand.

Comment: Would an answer in another programming language besides Maple also be acceptable?

Comment: Well, if there is no other solution I could write down a program to do this, but I would prefer some simple instructions of a computer algebra system.

Comment: Is it not possible to generate the "indices" $I=i_1<\dots <i_k$ and $J=j_1<\dots< j_k$ readily as lists, and then use Submatrix$(A,I,J)$ and Determinant to produce the matrix for the exterior power?

Comment: It is probably possible to write a procedure to compute the suited matrix (altough I don't know how to use Submatrix and Determinant to reach this goal), but is there not a command or a few commands that enable to compute all this in a simpler way?

Comment: Ok I finally wrote a procedure following ancientmathematician's advices. I would like to post it there as it may interest some people in the future, but when I try to copy and paste, it changes everything...